# Show SQL constraints in multiple tables

Tags: sql, constraints, sqlplus

Let say I have these 3 constraint given:

```
ALTER TABLE actor ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ACTORID PRIMARY KEY (actor_id);
ALTER TABLE film ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FILMID PRIMARY KEY (film_id);
ALTER TABLE film_actor ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FILMID1 FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES film;
```

I need to write sql to show these table constraints:

```
-- Check which constraints added in ACTOR table
SELECT OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION, INDEX_NAME 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ACTOR';

-- Check which constraints added in FILM_ACTOR table
SELECT OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION, INDEX_NAME 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FILM_ACTOR';
```

And the result end up like:

[image]

and

[image]

My question is, how can I combine two sql statements I wrote as 1 sql and also formatting the result displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would changing your where statement work?

Something like this:

```
SELECT OWNER, CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME, SEARCH_CONDITION, INDEX_NAME 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ACTOR' or table_name = 'film' or table_name ='film_actor';
```

Comment: But do you know how to do the formatting? Is the format sql in front of my constraints sql statement?

Comment: You could do a whole list of unions / joins to get it to display but I doubt it would be worth it?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. But I also need to format the result, the sql result shown with your code is still similar to the result I have in the post. In which the COLUMN, CONSTRAINT_NAME and others are the columns of the table. Do you know how to display is correctly?

Comment: Oh... Nothing, I figured it out